# How do I search using Laravel Scout Algolia and adding strings filter

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am trying to search using Laravel Scout Algolia with filtering ***LIKE Strings***

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $filter = $request->filter; // Filter {"name": "pan"}

    $q = $request->q;
    $results = Product::search($q)
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filter->name.'%')
        ->paginate(10);

    return $results;
}
```

This code is not working because where clause is running only on certain operations such as
`=, !=, IN, EXISTS, etc..`.

Problem is that if I used `=` operator it will be an exact match to a string while user may type part of the string.

Comment: I do not understand what is the issue, you don't know when to use `=`, `like`, `in`, etc?

Comment: It is case sensitive and exact match. For example if I want to filter by part of the word i cant